# Verify that API call was made from AWS Lambda (or another server)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

Is there any way I can check that a call is made from an expected lambda function or you can consider it as another server.

The use case is: I want to emit a websocket event to notify my web app when my EC2 status changes. (Do suggest a better way if any) My web socket server will be an EC2 instance. So I am wondering, if there is some way to allow calls to this specific API to be only from a valid AWS Lambda function?

Currently I am thinking maybe I can just use a shared secret ... but since this never expires, wonder if its a security risk?

**UPDATE**

A thought came to mind, isit ok to use asymmetric encryption like RSA for this?

Oh wait, is RSA not suitable for such data encryption? I read its for signing keys?

Comment: What sort of ec2 status change you are refering to? Did you look upon having EC2 status change -> Cloudwatch Alarm -> Lambda path

Comment: @Ashan yes where Lambda calls my server to emit change notifications to client (web apps) via websockets. Or is there a better way to update my apps directly from Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already set a EC2 state change trigger to a SNS topic you have created.

You can verify singature of SNS notification by processing the JSON body as instructed in AWS SNS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.verify.signature.html). It also has a Java [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.example.java.html) but if you want to use Python, here is an [example](http://www.artur-rodrigues.com/tech/2013/08/19/verifying-x509-signatures-in-python.html) for X509 verification part using `M2Crypto` module:

```
from M2Crypto import X509
from base64 import b64decode

cert = X509.load_cert_string(str(r.text))
pubkey = cert.get_pubkey()
pubkey.reset_context(md='sha1')
pubkey.verify_init()
pubkey.verify_update(str_to_sign.encode())
result = pubkey.verify_final(b64decode(signature))
if result != 1:
    raise Exception('Signature could not be verified')
else:
    return True
```

As advised in the doc, AWS SDK implemented for language might already have built-in ability just like for [Ruby](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/verifying-amazon-sns-message-authenticity/). It is good idea to check that before implementing this.

So basically, you should have the X509 that is used by SNS on the receiving server.

It is also recommended you to subscribe your SNS topic to a HTTPS endpoint so it will validate the authenticity of the server before sending the notification as a secure request. SNS supports verifying certificate authorities listed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.https.ca.html).

Comment: I didnt think about SNS but its a great idea. Thank you

Comment: Just as a good news, if you use lambda as a handler, you don't even need HTTPS part because it will validate it internally. Of course, X509 is still needed to validate the message.

Comment: Thats good to know, but I think I might have no choice but to use HTTPS to EC2 since I want to update clients via websockets. Or is there a better way? I read I can use AWS IOT too, but thats abit overboard?

Comment: You are right, IoT can trigger other resources but not vice versa except the active connections. You might need to sustain a connection to IoT from your EC2 if you still want to use it.